# Adding a leading zero via update query in Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with a column that contains 3 digit zip codes stored as text, and some of them are stored as 2 digit zips because leading zero is missing. I want to add the missing leading zeros for 2 digit zips.

I tried the query below but got a lot of errors and the result was not accurate. Should it be written with an `if` statement checking if the length is 2 characters then concatenate with 0? Or some other way?

This is what I tried:

```
Update TABLE set ZIPS = string(3 - len(ZIPS),"0")
```

I had the following error message:

> MS Access didn't update 1930 fields due to a type conversion failure, 0 records due to key violations, 0 records due to lock violations, o records due to validation rule violations.

Comment: Update TABLE set ZIPS = ZIPS & "0" WHERE Len(ZIPS) = 2. backup your current data first and run a SELECT statement first to check  whether expected data is returned: SELECT ZIPS FROM TABLE WHERE Len(ZIPS) = 2

Comment: Actually, `ZIPS = "0" & ZIPS WHERE Len(ZIPS)=2`. If you want to use String(): `ZIPS = String(3 - len(ZIPS),"0") & ZIPS`.

Comment: @June, correct. I mixed up trailing and leading. Don't understand why this question's been closed. Seems like Stackoverflow is getting more "rude" again.

Comment: Neither do I. I nominated for reopen.

Comment: I understand why it's closed, it doesn't provide a [mre]. For type conversion failures, one should provide the table definition, as well as if there are null values. Also, the query provided will set the field equal to only zeroes instead of adding zeroes which is weird

Comment: Question says field is text type with 2 and 3 digit values, shows attempted code, and quotes error message. Very simple and focused issue. Reproducible enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is with the function [`FORMAT()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530):

```
update tablename
set zips = format(zips, '000')
where len(zips) < 3
```

For these values:

```
zips
1
15
13
100
99
8
```

the result will be:

```
zips
001
015
013
100
099
008
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, I might suggest:

```
update YourTable set zips = "0" & zips where zips like "??"
```

Alternatively, the following is useful if you want to output 3 digits without updating the stored values:

```
select right("000" & zips, 3) from YourTable
```